What did the king sing?
The king stood atop a hill
Watching as his daughter fell
He wished to see her once more
Wondered when he'll do so.
"I will." he thought to himself.
As he growled, mourning
"I am..." he said, panting.
As his general completed his sentence.
As the king mourned, the general plead:
"Please, your Majesty! Don't-"
As the king said I already did.
The general asked:"Who stood by you, while you conquered all these lands?"
The king scoffed at his bravery.
"Please, your Majesty; who helped you through the first deaths?"
The king stared at him, "The one whom my gaze lays."
"Look onward." said the general.
"Look at the ground." said the king, as he looked upon his men.
"No, your majesty, look at the sky." the general thought.
The king sang, summarized the answers
He did as general thought, and looked...
What did he sing?
